# Change string date/time to be understandable for mathematica

Tags: date-and-time

I'm trying to convert a string of a data and time to be understandable for mathematica (I want to make time related plots).

However, I can get my head around how to do this.

For example:

```
temp = "Sun Jun 01 22:00:21 +0000 2014";
```

I have tried the following commands (and many more variations):

```
DateList[{temp, {"DayName", "Month", "Day", "Hour", "Minute", 
   "Second", "TimeZone", "Year"}}];
DateList[{temp, {"DayName", "Month", "Day", "Hour", ":", "Minute", 
   ":", "Second", "TimeZone", "Year"}}]
```

Both gave me this type of error:

```
DateString::str: "String \!\(\"Sun Jun 01 22:00:21 +0000 2014\"\) cannot be interpreted as a date in format {\!\(\"DayName\", \"Month\", \"Day\", \"Hour\", \"Minute\", \"Second\", \"TimeZone\", \"Year\"\)}."
```

Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!!

Comment: Hi @Lena, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you learn the basic rules of the site. Once you gain enough reputation by making [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) you will be able to vote up and down both questions and answers. [Your question has been answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), but its a good idea to wait a few hours for other answers before [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the best one for you.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with "TimeZone", that its not defined, and with using "Month" instead of "MonthName".

This works:

```
DateList[{"Sun Jun 01 22:00:21 2014", {"DayName", "MonthName", "Day", "Hour", "Minute", "Second", "Year"}}]
```

Are the strings in `temp` with fixed format? Then removing the characters will do

```
DateList[{StringDrop[temp, {21, 26}], {"DayName", "MonthName", "Day", "Hour", "Minute", "Second", "Year"}}]
```

Otherwise

```
DateList[ToString@ImportString[temp, "Table"][[1, {6, 2, 3, 4}]]]
```

I'm sure somebody else can work some magic to make this shorter and more efficient.

Comment: For me these commands do not work, and I don't quite understand why. If I use exactly your commands, I get this error:
`DateList[{"Sun Jun 01 22:00:21 2014", {"DayName", "MonthName", "Day", 
   "Hour", "Minute", "Second", "Year"}}]`
`DateString::str: String Sun Jun 01 22:00:21 2014 cannot be interpreted as a date in format {DayName,MonthName,Day,Hour,Minute,Second,Year}. >>`

Comment: @Lena, Strange, they do work for me. Anyhow the answer by Eldo is to my taste the most thorough and elegant. You should consider learning from that one, and even [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it if you think it does answer your original question. (Learn [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) why is that important)

Answer (score 3):

**Some options**

Your date

```
date = "Sun Jun 01 22:00:21 +0000 2014";
```

Eliminate wrong entry

```
rep = StringReplace[date, "+0000" -> ""]
```

> "Sun Jun 01 22:00:21  2014"

Convert to `List`

```
list = rep // DateList
```

> {2014, 6, 1, 22, 0, 21.}

Find day

```
day = DayName[list]
```

> Sunday

Consolidate

```
{day}~Join~list
```

> {Sunday, 2014, 6, 1, 22, 0, 21.}

Convert to `DateObject` @ GMT

```
obj = DateObject[list, TimeZone -> 0]
```

[image]

Convert to your local time

```
tzc = TimeZoneConvert[obj, $TimeZone]
```

[image]

Transform to `DateList`

```
tzc // DateList
```

> {2014, 6, 2, 0, 0, 21.}

Convert to  another `CalendarType`

```
DateObject[list, CalendarType -> "Jewish"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Manually fixing the timezone.

```
datecalc[t_] := Module[{},

  t2 = StringSplit[t, " " | ":"];
  tzsign = StringTake[t2[[7]], 1]; 
  tzhrs = ToExpression[StringTake[t2[[7]], {2, 3}]]; 
  tzmin = ToExpression[StringTake[t2[[7]], -2]];
  {hour, min} = ToExpression[t2[[{4, 5}]]];

  If[SameQ[tzsign, "+"],
   h2 = hour + tzhrs; m2 = min + tzmin,
   h2 = hour - tzhrs; m2 = min - tzmin];

  ymd = Take[DateList[{StringJoin[
        Riffle[Append[Take[t2, {2, 3}], Last@t2], " "]],
       {"MonthName", "Day", "Year"}}], 3];

  DateList[Join[ymd, {h2, m2}, {ToExpression[t2[[6]]]}]]]
```

Works for [UTC-02:30](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9202:30)

```
datecalc["Sun Jun 01 22:00:21 -0230 2014"]
```

> {2014, 6, 1, 19, 30, 21.}

and [UTC+13:45](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B13:45)

```
datecalc["Fri Dec 31 11:00:21 +1345 1999"]
```

> {2000, 1, 1, 0, 45, 21.}

Answer (score 1):

At first I tried this hack:

```
ClearAll;
temp = "Sun Jun 01 22:00:21 +0000 2014";
td = If[StringFreeQ[temp, "-"],  
   DateList[{temp, {"DayNameShort", " ", "MonthNameShort", " ", 
      "Day", " ", "Hour24", ":", "Minute", ":", "Second", " +", 
      "Millisecond", " ", "Year"}}], 
   DateList[{temp, {"DayNameShort", " ", "MonthNameShort", " ", 
      "Day", " ", "Hour24", ":", "Minute", ":", "Second", " -", 
      "Millisecond", " ", "Year"}}]
   ];
tx = If[StringFreeQ[temp, "-"], 
  DateList[td, 
   TimeZone -> Plus[(FractionalPart[Last[td]]* 100), $TimeZone] ],
      DateList[td, 
       TimeZone -> Plus[(-FractionalPart[Last[td]]* 100), $TimeZone]]]
(* {2014, 6, 1, 22, 0, 21.} *)
```

Since there is no "TimeZone" pattern match expression, I hacked the "Millisecond". However, millisecond is limited to 3 digits, so we get round off errors.

Next I tried this:

```
ClearAll;
temp = "Sun Jun 01 22:00:21 +0000 2014";
DateList[{StringDrop[
   StringRotateRight[StringInsert[temp, " ", -1], 5], -7], {"Year", 
   " ", "DayNameShort", " ", "MonthNameShort", " ", "Day", " ", 
   "Hour24", ":", "Minute", ":", "Second"}}, 
 TimeZone -> 
  Plus[(ToExpression[
     StringJoin[
      StringTrim[
       StringTake[
        StringRotateRight[StringInsert[temp, " ", -1], 
         5], {-7, -4}]], 
      StringTrim[
       ToString[
        N[Rationalize[
          ToExpression[
            StringTrim[
             StringTake[
              StringRotateRight[StringInsert[temp, " ", -1], 
               5], {-3, -1}]]]/60]]], "0"]
      ]]), $TimeZone]]
(* {2014, 6, 1, 22, 0, 21.} *)
```

Add space to end, rotate the string, and adjust the date pattern expression. If you put this as a Module function would have more freedom to reduce rotations. Still not certain about the TimeZone stuff.